# Are variable length integers treated differently if passed by command line arguement

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments

I just want to write a simple program to find the maximum of 2 integers.
If I pass the integers to the below program via command line and if they are of variable length, the answer is different:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
def main():
        a = sys.argv[1]
        b = sys.argv[2]
        print 'the first variable is', a
        print 'the second variable is', b
        maximum(a,b)

def maximum(a,b):
        print 'The value of a is', a
        print 'The value of b is', b
        if a > b:
                print 'The bigger number is', a
        else:
                print 'The bigger number is', b

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

To this program, if I give inputs like 2,3 or 10,11 or 123,131 it works correctly.
But if I give inputs like 3,10 it gives the wrong answer.
But if I hardcode the values like 3,10 inside the program, it works fine.

So my question is does the argv[] handle variable length differently or is that I have made a stupid mistake somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: I got it. If I use int to convert them and then compare, it works fine. But what was happening in my initial program. It didn't throw an error. So how was it comparing the values earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line arguments are **strings**, not numbers. You have to convert them to numbers before you compare them:

```
a = float(sys.argv[1])
b = float(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: I'd use `int` instead of `float`, since the question specifically asked about integers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to cast your command line arguments. Secondly, you should never reinvent the wheel, use the built-in `max` function.